How to lag values across several rows in PySpark
I have code in SAS that I'm trying to convert to PySpark. In SAS, this scenario was accomplished using a combo of lag() and retain. I have a dataset of claims that need to be rolled up, so to speak, but only if a claim meets specific criteria. In the end, I need to move the admission date to the last record - if it's in a sequence, which is identified with Status = 30, along with some additional criteria specified below.
Example data, before:



ClaimID
PatientID
HspID
FromDt
ThruDt
Status




352
431
001
1/15/23
1/21/23
01


854
431
002
3/1/23
3/31/23
30


053
431
002
4/1/23
4/30/23
30


893
431
002
5/1/23
5/3/23
01


981
431
002
6/1/23
6/30/23
30


302
431
002
7/1/23
7/15/23
01


132
410
008
4/1/23
4/15/23
02


664
613
008
3/1/23
3/31/23
30


953
613
008
4/1/23
4/30/23
30


351
613
008
5/1/23
5/31/23
30


287
613
008
6/1/23
6/30/23
30


511
613
008
7/1/23
7/11/23
02



Example data, after (desired result):



ClaimID
PatientID
HspID
FromDt
ThruDt
Status




352
431
001
1/15/23
1/21/23
01


893
431
002
3/1/23
5/3/23
01


302
431
002
6/1/23
7/15/23
01


132
410
008
4/1/23
4/15/23
02


511
613
008
3/1/23
7/11/23
02



The criteria to roll these claims up is the following:
PatientID = Previous row's PatientID
HspID = Previous row's HspID
Date difference of FromDt - Previous row's ThruDt = 0 or 1. (example using claim ID 053 which lags data from claim ID 854, 4/1/23 - 3/31/23 = 1)
Previous row's Status = 30
In the examples above:
Claim IDs: 854, 053 and 893 are all related to one visit at a hospital. Therefore, I need to keep the last record, 893, and move the admit date of 3/1/23 from ID 854 to this record.
Claim IDs: 981, 302 are related to one visit at a hospital. Therefore, I need to keep the last record, 302, and move the admit date of 6/1/23 from ID 981 to this record.
Claim IDs: 664, 953, 351, 287 and 511 are related to one visit at a hospital. Therefore, I need to keep the last record, 511, and move the admit date of 3/1/23 from ID 664 to this record.
Claim IDs: 352 and 132 are unique and are not part of a sequence but need to be kept in the final output.

Still curious to know other solutions but I found a way to solve this by using lag and lead to determine if it's the first record or last record of a sequence and created new columns to note that. I also identified records that are in a sequence. So, in my example, claim 854 is identified as Start, claim 893 is identified as End. Claims 854, 053, 893 are all identified as a sequence. I can then filter out 053 and do another lag to get the from date from the Start record and move it to the End record.
